# How to identify that new file is updated?

Tags: sharepoint-server, event-receivers

I have created an event receiver with ItemUpdated properties. I want to update some field if new document is uploaded. But whenever the any field is updated, ItemUpdated is fired. I want to check that my code is run only if new document is uploaded.

Is there any way that file is uploaded or properties updated ?

Comment: Then wouldn't you want to use ItemAdding or ItemAdded?

Comment: @EricAlexander no, i have already added a file to doc library. now when i again upload same file, it fires ItemUpdated. But how can i identify that its a file updated or field updated ?

Comment: Your question wasn't clear in that case. There is no difference in field or file modification in this situation, both fire ItemUpdating.

Comment: @EricAlexander so how can i identify that file is modified ? is that possible to find out ?

Comment: I don't know if in the Before and AfterProperties if you can tell if the overwrite check box was checked or tell if there is a file size difference, that would be my only guess

Comment: yes its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution as per @Eric Alexander comment. We can find the file size difference so we will identify that it is file updated or field update.